# Match a text in a file and print text above that matching another pattern

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file, something like this

```
|| SUMMERCAMP ||
| Martin Mayer |
| Hunter David |
| Vanessa Lawrence |
| Jake Corper |
| Claudia Jones |

|| Discoparty ||
| Pavel Chavetzny |
| Julian Tannenbaum |
| Cord Kruger |
| Jennifer Lowenstein |
```

I now want to match let's say Claudia Jones, and I want as result || SUMMERCAMP || (I do not need the pipe). I just need to match a line and search upwards from there until I match for example ||, and print that line. If Cord Kruger is matched, I need || Discoparty || as a result (again with or without the pipes). Tried sed, to no avail. All help is greatly appreciated.

I tried using

```
awk -F \| '/^\|{2}/ { grp=$1;next } $1=="$groupmember" { print "||"grp"||" }' $GROUPSRC
```

for example (based on what Raman said), where $GROUPSRC is the file I am searching in, and $groupmember is a variable which I give to the script in a while read loop.

I also tried

```
grep -B 10
```

but that does not work, since that will look upwards for the next 10 lines, and sometimes I do not have a "||" in those, or I have more than one, which of course upsets the result.

Thanks for the answers so far and sorry for not asking a clearer question.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: Another way, taking advantage of `ed`'s ability to search backwards in a file: `printf "%s\n" '/User 4/;?GROUP?;.p' | ed -s yourfile` (Search for the first line matching `User 4`, then search backwards from that line for a match of `GROUP`, and print that line.)

Comment: Rephrased the question to make it clearer, and included examples of what I tried, can we reopen it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk:

```
 awk -F \| -v usr="Claudia Jones" '/^\|{2}/ { grp=$3;next } $2==" "usr" " { print "||"grp"||" }' file
```

Set the field delimiter to "|" and set a variable usr to 4. Then when the line begins with 2 "|", set a variable grp to the third delimited field and skip to the next line. When the second field is equal to " User " followed by the passed usr variable and then another space, print the grp variable with "||" prefixed and appended.

Comment: I tried this (check above), but either I am too inexperienced or there is something else, the result from this awk always stayed empty.

Comment: Yeah. You changed your example data since I posted the original answer. Try the amendment.

Comment: I know I did, Raman. Not done with bad intentions. The question got closed, and I realised I should have made it more precise. Apologies.

Comment: Thanks Raman, you are 100% correct, it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -ne '$g = $_ if /GROUP/; print $g if /User 4$/' file
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line and runs the code for each line;
- `$_` contains the current line, we store it in the variable `$g` if the line contains `GROUP`;
- we print the stored group if the line contains `User 4`. The dollar sign means "end of string", it's needed here not to match `User 42` etc.

Answer (score 0):

If your records have empty lines between them, you can do it like this with `awk`:

```
awk '/User 4/ { print $1 }' RS= FS='\n' < infile
```

Output:

```
|| GROUP 1 ||
```